# Add an attribute to the module in which a Python decorator is running

Tags: python, module, attributes, decorator

I'd like to write a Python decorator that adds an attribute to the module in which a decorator is running, i.e.

```
@procedure
def whatever(arg1, arg2):
    # do things
    return
```

should add an attribute `attr` to the module where `whatever` is found. I've tried writing the decorator `procedure` (defined in another file) as follows

```
def procedure(fn):
    global attr
    attr = SomeClass()
    return fn
```

but `attr` is added to the module where `procedure` is defined, not to the module where `procedure` runs. Is there some other way to do this?

Comment: Why do you need a decorator at all if it is not doing anything to the function object passed to it? Just make `procedure` a regular function that takes no argument and call it in the module where `attr` is needed instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you want to *mark* a function, such that some user of the module where it is defined will be able to know that it belongs to some category of functions. You could write a simple decorator like this:

```
def special(fn):
    globals().setdefault("__specials__", set()).add(fn)
    return fn
```

Then you can write a module that uses this decorator, like this:

```
"""Module 'has_specials'"""
def regular():
    return "meh"

@special
def important():
    return "wow!"

@special
def bigshot():
    return "HA"
```

This can then be used by another module like this:

```
import has_specials

if hasattr(has_specials, "__specials__"):
    for fn in has_specials.__specials__:
        print("%-20s: %s" % (fn.__name__, fn))
```

The code above will import the module, and list the `special` functions:

```
important           : <function important at 0x000002435FD51488>
bigshot             : <function bigshot at 0x000002435FD51510>
```

Comment: Comment cleanup is in order - I removed mine (and will remove this one shortly) - I think your should be, too, as they relate to a previous version of the answer. Thanks.